# Aviso de erro no console ao rodar ionic app

Tags: ionic

criei uma app pelo ionic creator. Tenho um form para cadastro e ao clicar em qualquer campo do formulário o seguinte aviso aparece no console:

> 'webkitMovementX' is deprecated. Please use 'movementX' instead. ........   ionic.bundle.js:1173

Já me deram a sugestão de atualizar o ionic, já atualizei a lib, também, e foi para a versão  Ionic, v1.2.4-nightly-1917, sendo que tem que ser a v1.2.4-nightly-2019, pelo que me falaram.
Quando tentei reinstalar o ionic, esse mensagem apareceu:

[image: Print da mensagem]

Atualizei o npm e uma cassetada de coisas foi atualizada tb.
E no final, aparece isso: Vcs veem os ERRS!?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém teu alguma ideia ou sugestão?

Comment: Já atualizou o npm?

Comment: Como atualizo o npm @MarcoAurélioDeleu?

Comment: fazendo isso?
npm install -g npm?

Comment: Atualizei vários pacotes e não ajudou, quero dizer, atualizou muitos pacotes, mas o ionic.bundle.js

Answer (score 0):

Eu já passei por um erro semelhante e pelo menos no meu caso era problema de permissão de usuário. Tente executar o seguinte comando:

```
sudo chown -R meuusuario /usr/local/lib/
```

Depois instale o cordova e o ionic:

```
npm install -g cordova ionic
```

Answer (score -1):

Na sua aplicação você está usando a função "webkitMovementX" que está desatualizada, utilize a movementX.

Isso é só um aviso, não é um erro. Essa função pode ter problemas que na versão mais nova já foram corrigidos.

Comment: É bem provável que quem esteja usando a função obsoleta seja o próprio Ionic e não o autor da pergunta. Sua resposta não é relevância ao problema.

Comment: Não Lucas, não estou usando por conta própria essa função. É do próprio ionic.bundle.js

Comment: Obrigado por retornar, achei o link desse bug no ionic: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/4259

Comment: Esse link, infelizmente, não ajudou.